# Compiled Typescript path is not resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following folder structure:

```
/src
   /ts
     /controllers
        controller1.ts
     /routes
        route1.ts
     index.ts
```

And my `tsconfig.json` is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/ts",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "dist/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "node",
      "express"
    ],
    "pretty": false
  },
  "include":[
    "src/ts/**/*.ts",
    "dist/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "coverage"
  ]
}
```

As an example, my `route1.ts` has an import as

```
import controller1 from 'controllers/controller1';
```

Which resolves fine. However, when I compile `node_modules/.bin/tsc`, these files are compiled in the `dist` folder as

```
const controller1 = require("controllers/controller1");
```

And when I run the server I get

```
error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'controllers/controller1'
```

How can I get the compiled typescript path to be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't rewrite import paths: see [this declined suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479).  You'll have to either use relative import paths or add the `dist` directory to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable at runtime.

Comment: That's the whole point of defining a `baseUrl` and `paths`. If it cannot use these to compile TS to JS, then what is the point of these properties in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: No, [according to the TypeScript team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479#issuecomment-300240856), the purpose of these options was to be able to tell TypeScript about the module resolution rules that your runtime environment will use.  For example, if you knew that you were going to set `NODE_PATH` at runtime, you could set `baseUrl` to match.