# tsc is not registering path aliases during production build

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have created a build script as follows.

```
"scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register server/main.ts ",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && nuxt build && tsc",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "lintfix": "tslint -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "clean": "rimraf dist"
  },
```

In my tsconfig.json path aliases are as following.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["server/*"],
      "@/*": [
        "client/*"
      ],
    },
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/vue-app",
      "vuex-class-component/dist",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "server/**/*",
    "client/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I am running `npm run build` and trying to run as "node main.js"

But it gives the following error.

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/models/projects/datasource'
```

When I use a relative path (i.e. ../models/projects/datasource), it works fine. How can I compile these paths for a production build?

In `start` script it works fine. i.e. works with `npm run start`.

My Directory structure is as below.

```
/client
  /some other client side folders
/server
  /models
    /projects
      datasource.ts
/package.json
```

Comment: can you post your folder structure and your full tsconfig?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512141/compiled-typescript-path-is-not-resolved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiled Typescript path is not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512141/compiled-typescript-path-is-not-resolved)

Comment: @Kousha Seems that answers the question of "Is it possible or not?" I have seen some articles where using node packages they are solving it. But they are not being maintained anymore. e.g. following article uses tscpaths, but tscpaths is not being maintained anymore.

https://medium.com/@jimcraft123hd/setting-up-path-alias-in-typescript-and-tsc-build-without-error-9f1dbc0bccd2

So I am unable to agree that it is not possible at all.

Comment: This also seems to be claiming but not working for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586700/9263418

Answer (score 5):

We can use following package for this purpose.

```
npm install --save-dev tsc-alias
```

Add it after your existing tsc as following which will convert all paths.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
}
```

Still open to any better answers.

Comment: This seems to do nothing at all for me, despite having your exact setup. It just straight up doesn't convert any paths.